# Why isn't [1,2,3] equal to itself in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with arrays in Javascript today and noticed this little gem:

```
alert([1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]); //alerts false
```

It strikes me as rather odd that the array is not equal to itself.

But then I noticed this, which was even weirder:

```
alert([1, 2, 3] == "1,2,3");  //alerts true
```

**?!?!?!?!!!?**

Why in the world is `[1, 2, 3]` not `==` to itself but is `==` to the string?

I realize that `==` is [not the same](http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/stricteq.html) as `===`. Even so, what evilness could cause Mr. Javascript do such weird things?

Comment: When a language does what its spec says it should do that isn't evil. Given you already know that `==` and `===` do things differently doesn't that answer your question about the comparison between that array and string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't equality check work with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30820611/1048572)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, so first you need to understand how javascript treats values in your program. All of your variables that you create are going to merely be *references* to a location in memory where that object is stored. Therefore, when you do this:

```
alert( [1,2,3] == [1,2,3] );
```

...it does three things:

1. Place an array ([1,2,3]) onto the heap
2. Place another array ([1,2,3]) onto the heap (notice it will have a different memory location)
3. Compare the two references. They point to different objects in different locations in memory, thus it is considered not equal.

You can check for some sane behavior by running this code:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = a;
alert (a == b)   // Result is true. Both point to the same object.
```

Now for your question about the string

When you use the `==` operator tries to convert the two operands to the same type (evil behavior...I know...)

When it does this, it decides to convert both to a string before it does the compare (thus the result is really `"1,2,3" === "1,2,3"`, which evaluates to true.

I can't give you a complete picture, as there are few people who understand every nuance of the madness that is JavaScript, but hopefully this clears some of the fog.

Comment: `==` doesn't have evil behaviour, it has clearly defined behaviour that in this situation is less helpful than what you'd get from `===`. Or maybe it's _more_ helpful: it really depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @nnnnnn, it has *counter-intuitive* behavior, thus it is evil. The example above reveals some of the evil nature of `==`, but not all of it. For example, `false == undefined` is false, `false==null` is false, but `null==undefined` is true. It is well defined, but completely counter-intuitive (and if transitivity is a basis for what is "correct", then the results are flat out wrong.)

Comment: @nnnnnn, wait, copied the wrong example (late night). The example that breaks transitivity is this: `'0'==0` is true, `'' == 0` is true, but `'0'==''` is false. Astonishingly counter-intuitive.

Comment: The behavior of `==` in regards to arrays, though, isn't really all that counter-intuitive, is it? They're different arrays, that happen to contain the same elements.

Comment: @Dave, Sure, from the standpoint of writing the interpreter it might make sense, but is it *really* that useful to check if two arrays are stored in the same location in memory? To put it another way, how often would you need the current behavior as opposed to comparing the elements within the array? JavaScript believed the former was more likely. Python believed the latter was more likely. I agree with Python.

Comment: It depends on what you're writing, obviously. But when you don't have operator overloading, that kind of functionality should come from methods. Both usages of `==` are pretty typical; I just don't consider it counter-intuitive at all. The issue with strings v. numbers is to do with JS's bizarre ideas of type conversion, not the `==` operator.

Comment: If two sides of loose equality check aka ```==``` are at the same type (array for instance) they won't get coerced toPrimitive,, am i right?? 

Answer (score 6):

> `==` operator
>
> [..] If either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string if possible. [..] If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

That is to say, `[1, 2, 3]` converted to a string equals `"1,2,3"`. One array object does not equal another array object though.

Answer (score 4):

For the first part, you are creating two distinct objects as arrays are just objects and since you created two of them, they are both unique.

Answer (score 3):

Because `==` only coerces *if it has to* to get the same type (e.g, only when the types of the operands are different). When doing

```
alert([1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]); //alerts false
```

...no coercion is required; both are objects. They're not the **same** object, so it's `false`. People think of `==` as the "coercing" equality operator, and it is, but the key is that it only coerces *if it has to*.

But doing

```
alert([1, 2, 3] == "1,2,3");  //alerts true
```

...involves operands of *different* types: string and object. So coercion is done. In this case, the object is coerced to string as though with `String(obj)`, which invokes its default `toString` behavior, which for arrays is `.join()`. `join` defaults to `","` as the separator, so the resulting string matches `"1,2,3"`. (You can find the full logic of why the object gets coerced to string [in the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).)

Answer (score 2):

The first comparison fails because a basic comparison of two objects will check to see if they are literally the same referenced object, not if the two objects have the same values. If you wish to compare two arrays, you'll have to loop over the values.

```
function arrayCompare(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
  for (var i = 0, len = arr1.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Just remember that this is not a recursive comparison, so it will only work on an array of primitive values.

The second comparison works because == will attempt to coerce the types of the arguments, and when you convert an array to a string, that is the result.

```
[1,2,3].toString() === '1,2,3'
```

Answer (score 1):

The two `Array` objects are distinct, and thus not equal when using the `==` comparison. To compare them, you'd need to loop, checking the index in both are identical (and being recursive if the elements are `Array`s too or `Object`s).

The second is because the `Array` had its `toString()` implicitly called which returned `'1,2,3'` (try it).

This is because by the rules of a `==` (non strict) comparison in ECMAScript, the left hand operator was coerced to a `String` (`==` does type conversion).