# Equality object-String using == in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, equality

I'm dealing with a strange situation with Javascript,

I know that the strange moments of JS (like this) are not strange at all, simply the code working completely predictably and exactly as specified.

```js
var materials_1 = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium'];
var materials_2 = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium'];
var materials_3 = "Hydrogen,Helium,Lithium";

console.log(materials_1 == materials_3); //True
console.log(materials_2 == materials_3); //True
console.log(materials_1 == materials_2); //False

console.log([] == []);  //False
```

But, can someone provide me a detailed explanation when using `==` in this kind of equality comparaison ?

Thank you for your light.

NB: I have checked [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript), this question does not treat the comparison case with a string !

Comment: Also [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: @MohammadUsman, i have checked this questions ! My question is more oriented object-string and no comparison operator!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314635/why-isnt-1-2-3-equal-to-itself-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `==` operator means equality with conversion.**

When used with two different types, one (or both) will be coerced to a common type for the comparison to be performed. That's what's happening with the first two test cases (array == string).

**[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)**

> **Equality (==)**
>
> The equality operator converts the operands if they are
> not of the same type, then applies strict comparison. If both operands
> are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are
> equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

So, when two objects are compared (arrays are objects), they are already of the same type, so the object *reference* is compared against the other. With objects, it's not the data that is being compared, it's the actual object in memory, so the two variables are compared to see if they point to the same memory location, which, in your case, they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Even if `materials_1` and `materials_2` contain the same `string` values, they are actually two different `Arrays`. When you compare them, you are actually comparing references, that's why something like that will always be `false`, regardless of the content of the Arrays.

The same applies for `[] == []`. Each `[]` creates a new empty array and then you compare the references to them.

However, when you compare them to `materials_3`, which is a `string` **(using `==`)**, JS will call [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) on the other arrays to convert them to their primitive value. As the value returned from `valueOf()` is not a primitive either, it will call `toString()` on it, which returns `"Hydrogen,Helium,Lithium"`. As strings are primitives, now the comparison will be done by value and return `true`.

You can find more about [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) on MDN:

> JavaScript calls the `valueOf` method to convert an object to a primitive value. You rarely need to invoke the `valueOf`method yourself; JavaScript automatically invokes it when encountering an object where a primitive value is expected.
>
> By default, the `valueOf`method is inherited by every object descended from [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Every built-in core object overrides this method to return an appropriate value. If an object has no primitive value, `valueOf`returns the object itself.

You can see that in action here:

```js
function ObjectWrapper(actualObject) {
  this.actualObject = actualObject || {};
}

ObjectWrapper.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  console.log('valueOf');
  
  return this.actualObject; // Not a primitive.
};

ObjectWrapper.prototype.toString = function() {
  console.log('toString');
  
  return this.actualObject.toString();
};

const foo = new ObjectWrapper([1, 2, 3]);
const bar = '1,2,3';

console.log(foo == bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript tries to convert both the variables under comparison to same similar types when == operator is used and at least one of the operand is primitive.
[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

So in your case,

Case 1 : 
materials_1 ==  materials_3 is processed as materials_1.toString() == materials_3 (Which turns out to be true)

Case 2 : Same as that of case 1

Case 3 : Here both the operands are of same type (i.e. Array). As Objects are compared based on references, they would obviously have different memory location and hence they will not be equal.

Comment: *Javascript tries to convert both the objects under comparison* No, objects are not converted only primitives are.

Comment: If only primitives are converted, case 1 and 2 under question should not return true - right?

Comment: I meant that your statement is not correct when its an object and an object being compared (you wrote *both* the objects). If it's an object == primitive, then there is only one object.

Comment: Oops! My bad. Thanks for correcting me.