# Check if array is empty or includes the value, typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I check if array includes the value this way:

```
testArray.includes(value)
```

I need to do the same action if array is empty OR it includes the value. So I have this condition:

```
if (testArray == [] || testArray.includes(value)) {
    // do something
}
```

But `typescript` is trying to execute the second part of this condition even if `testArray == []`. So I receive an error `testArray.includes is underfined`.

I understand that I can fix it this way:

```
if (testArray == []) {
    // do something
} else if (testArray.includes(value)) {
    // do the same thing
}
```

But it doesn't look nice. **Is there a way to put it in one if?**

`testArray` is an openapi query parameter, if it's important.

Comment: `testArray == []` will always be false. See: [Why doesn't equality check work with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30820611) and [Why isn't \[1,2,3\] equal to itself in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7314635) Moreover, if you get `testArray.includes is underfined` then you don't have an empty array, you have some sort of value that is not an array. Likely an object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The array is a `reference type`. When you would like to check it with `[ ]`, they aren't equal. They're different; checking this condition with `length` is better. So, based on your code, you should do something like this :

```
if (!testArray || testArray.length == 0 || testArray.includes(value)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work too – `testArray. length is underfined` error

Comment: Could you share your `testArray`'s items? I updated my code. Please try it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isValueInArrayOrEmpty(updated) {
    console.log(Boolean(updated instanceof Array && (updated.length == 0 || (updated.length > 0 && updated.includes(value)))));
}
let value = "hello";
let updated = [];
isValueInArrayOrEmpty(updated);
let updated2 = "hello";
isValueInArrayOrEmpty(updated2);
let updated3 = Object;
isValueInArrayOrEmpty(updated3);
let updated4 = [Object];
isValueInArrayOrEmpty(updated4);
let updated5 = ["hello"];
isValueInArrayOrEmpty(updated5);
let updated6 = ["not hello"];
isValueInArrayOrEmpty(updated6);

VM815:2 true
VM815:2 false
VM815:2 false
VM815:2 false
VM815:2 true
VM815:2 false
```

Answer (score -1):

`if (testArray == [] || testArray.includes(value)) { // do something }`

In case of OR operator if the first condition is true it will skip rest all conditions. With that said your first condition testArray == [] is false , hence its executing the second part of condition. Probably your array is not empty array its having undefined value as it might not be initialized. Hence its throwing error.