# Why is v2 == v2 false when it should be true?

Tags: javascript, compare, logic

I have an issue with my JavaScript code that is so stupid that I doubt anyone can help. But here it is: There is a variable called `v2` and apparently if I do `v2 == v2` it returns `false`. I can't figure out how the *heck* it got that logic. I tested that because `v2` contains the value `NaN` and no matter what `v2 == NaN` is `false`. I am trying to make a vector-path calculator program that enables you to insert code that indicates the path that an imaginary "pointer" is supposed to take and return the displacement X and Y values and the total distance traveled.

```js
var pointer = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  length: 0,
  move: function(dir,mag){
      var rounding = 100;
      var direction = dir * (Math.PI / 180);
      this.x += Math.round(rounding * (Math.cos(direction) * mag)) / rounding;
      this.y += Math.round(rounding * (Math.sin(direction) * mag)) / rounding;
      this.length += Number(mag);
      document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = this.x;
      document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = this.y;
      document.getElementById("l").innerHTML = this.length;
      print("&#x2022; vector moves pointer to (" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")");
  }
};
var variables = {
  get: function(id){
      return(this.e[id]);
  },
  set: function(id,v){
      this.e[id] = Number(v);
      print("&#x25a3; variable '" + id + "' was set to " + Number(v));
  },
  math: function(id1,op,id2){
      id2 = id2 || id1;
      var a = "";
      if(op == "+"){
          this.e[id1] += this.e[id2];
          a = "added with";
      }else if(op == "-"){
          this.e[id1] -= this.e[id2];
          a = "subtracted by";
      }else if(op == "*"){
          this.e[id1] *= this.e[id2];
          a = "multiplied by";
      }else if(op == "/"){
          this.e[id1] /= this.e[id2];
          a = "divided by";
      }else if(op == "%"){
          this.e[id1] %= this.e[id2];
          a = "modded by";
      }else if(op == "&"){
          if(this.e[id1] >= this.e[id2]){
              this.e[id1] = this.e[id1] - (this.e[id1] - this.e[id2]);
          }else{
              this.e[id1] = this.e[id2] + (this.e[id1] - this.e[id2]);
          }
          a = "bitwise-AND-modified by";
      }else if(op == "|"){
          this.e[id1] == (this.e[id1] + this.e[id2]) / 2;
          a = "bitwise-OR-modified by";
      }else if(op == "^"){
          this.e[id1] == Math.pow(this.e[id1],this.e[id2]);
          a = "powered by";
      }else if(op == "$"){
          this.e[id1] == Math.log(this.e[id2]) / Math.log(this.e[id1]);
          a = "logged by";
      }
      print("&#x221a; variable '" + id1 + "' was " + a + " variable" + id2);
  },
  e: {}
};
function run(){
  pointer.x = 0;
  pointer.y = 0;
  pointer.length = 0;
  document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = "<h2>Console</h2>";
  var code = document.getElementById("input").value.split(";");
  for(var i = 0; i < code.length; i++){
      var fn = code[i].split(" ");
      var n = fn[0];
      if(n == "vector"){
          var v1 = Number(fn[1]);
          var v2 = Number(fn[2]);
          if(v1 == NaN){
              v1 = variables.get(fn[1]) || 0;
          }
          if(v2 == NaN){
              v2 = variables.get(fn[2]) || 0;
          }
          alert(v2 == v2);
          pointer.move(v1,v2);
      }
      if(n == "var"){
          var v = Number(fn[2]);
          if(v == NaN){
              v = variables.get(fn[2]) || 0;
          }
          variables.set(fn[1],v);
      }
      if(n == "calc"){
          variables.math(fn[1],fn[2],fn[3]);
      }
  }
}
window.onerror = function(e){
  alert(e);
};
function print(msg){
  document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<p class='msg'>" + msg + "</p>";
}
```

```css
.msg{
    background: #aaffcc;
}
.msg:hover{
    background: #88ffaa;
    transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vectors Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="input" placeholder="Input code here"></textarea>
        <p><button onclick="run();">Run code</button></p>
        <p><b>X displacement:</b> <span id="x">0</span></p>
        <p><b>Y displacement:</b> <span id="y">0</span></p>
        <p><b>Total distance:</b> <span id="l">0</span></p>
        <div style="border: 1px solid #000000;" id="console">
            <h2>Console</h2>
        </div>
        <details>
            <summary><h2>Help</h2></summary>
            <p>Seperate each line by a <code>;</code> semicolon. Use each command like this: <code>function param1 param2; function param1 param2;</code>. The last function doesn't need a semicolon after it.</p>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Function</th>
                    <th>Parameters</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Example</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>vector</td>
                    <td>direction,magnitude</td>
                    <td>Moves the pointer <code>magnitude</code> units in the direction of <code>direction</code> degrees. 0 degrees is right-facing.</td>
                    <td><code>vector 0 10;</code> moves the pointer 10 units to the right (x+=10, y+=0)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </details>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why is there a logic issue that makes a variable claim it is not equal to itself? Did I do something wrong? Is there something wrong with my browser (Google Chrome, most recent version as of **16 Aug 2023**)? Is something wrong with the JavaScript language itself? What is going on? And, most importantly, is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: `Number.isNaN(v2)`

Comment: `NaN == NaN` is false. `NaN` is never equal to anything, even itself.

Comment: it's not always NaN causing the issue (but likely) if you have NaN or are evaluating an array, object or anything complex then a deeper comparision method is required

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314635/why-isnt-1-2-3-equal-to-itself-in-javascript

Comment: Please make all of these into an answer so that I can use it to mark this question as closed. Thank you guys! I never knew these things.

Comment: Uh, nevermind, the system already closed it. However these answers are still accessible right?